# Angular 5 - uploads disappear after publishing new version

Tags: c#, .net, angular, api

In an angular 5 app with a .net core backend, a user can upload attachments for his/her projects. The attachments are being send to the .NET Core backend and are saved inside the WebRootPath in a folder with the name of the project code.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/projects/{id}/upload")]
    [Consumes("application/json", "application/json-patch+json", "multipart/form-data")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAttachment(int id, FileForUpload upload)
    {
        var project = await _orbaAgent.GetDefaultProject(id);

        if (upload != null && upload.File != null && upload.File.Length > 0)
        {
            var file = upload.File;

            string serverPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath) ? _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath : _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            serverPath = Path.Combine(serverPath, "attachments", project.Code);

            if (!Directory.Exists(serverPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath);
            }

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(serverPath, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }            

        return Ok();
    }
```

The location of the attachments becomes 'app/attachments/'projectcode'/.

To download the files, I use an anchor element on the html page

```
 <a href="attachments/{{defaultProject.code}}/{{att.name}}" download>{{att.name}}</a>
```

Uploading/downloading works perfect.
The only problem is that when I deploy a new version of the application, the app/attachment folder dissapears and so do all of the attachments.

Is there any way to prevent the deletion of this folder for new versions? Or if this is not possible, should I save the files somewhere else?